# Use the destructor to do work

Tags: c++, raii, object-oriented-analysis

I have a class Transaction that holds a set of requests.
Every X seconds the requests in the current transaction are set, and the list of requests is cleared.

Is it ok to design the class Transaction in such way that it will send the requests in the transaction during its destruction, by the destructor?

This means that we allocate a new Transaction, add to it new requests as long as it still alive, and once the destructor is called all the requests will be sent.

This way we can guarantee that:

1. All transactions are sent (as long as we don't leak Transaction objects).
2. It is impossible to add changes to a transaction after it was sent.

Is this considered to be a good practice? Or would it be better to use a SendRequests method to send all the requests and clear the list?

Comment: *"Is it ok to design the class Transaction in such way that it will send the requests in the transaction during its destruction, by the destructor?"* No -Why would you think this?

Comment: That's a terrible idea. Imaging you start a transaction, do a few bits of the required actions in it and something throws. Your destructor is called and commits an incomplete mess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A destructor has only one purpose in the C++ language.  That is to manage (so it could log, use a helper object or function, *etc*) the release of resources acquired in the constructor as per RAII.  Any other use is going to get you into trouble sooner or later.

Comment: This is what I thought. Thanks!

Comment: ... unless you know the standard well and can use this tool for other purposes (like benchmarking, counting, etc.) trouble-free.

Comment: @bobah Why not use a templated wrapper to do that rather than pollute the dtor?  That way you keep it generic. And these kind of shenanigans can easily get you into trouble no matter how much you think "you know the standard well".

Comment: @PaulEvans - RAII based tools are in general easier to factor out for reuse. Wrappers only became "zero-overhead" in C++14 where perfect arguments and return value forwarding is possible.

Comment: @bobah Good point and I agree that sometimes we must compromise.  But I'm talking about best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You'd usually do exactly the opposite -- be explicit about the positive branch (the one resulting in the commit), but have rollback branch RAII-based to guarantee the consistent commit-or-rollback behaviour. Primarily because there are problems with throwing from destructors and implementing a no-throw rollback is usually easier than doing the same for commit by far.

Answer (score 0):

You should only perform actions that actually deconstruct the object at hand inside the destructor of a class.

Destructors are solely meant for clean-up tasks *only concerning the current object*. Triggering external communication at the end-of-life cycle of such an object will definitely get you into trouble.

One example problem occurs during subclassing and polymorphism:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  A() {
    std::cout << "Construct A" << std::endl;
  }

  virtual ~A() {
    std::cout << "Deconstruct A" << std::endl;
    this->doWork();
  }

  virtual void doWork() {
    std::cout << "Dummy virtual worker function in A" << std::endl;
  }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  B() {
    std::cout << "Construct B" << std::endl;
  }

  virtual ~B() {
    std::cout << "Deconstruct B" << std::endl;
  }

  void doWork() {
    std::cout << "Actual worker function in B" << std::endl;
  };
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  A* aTest = new B();
  aTest->doWork();

  delete aTest;

  return 0;
}
```

This results in the output

```
Construct A
Construct B
Actual worker function in B
Deconstruct B
Deconstruct A
Dummy virtual worker function in A
```

So when you subclass your class and override virtual functions in it, you lose the overridden functionality when you reach the base class's destructor. In the example, this happens when `this->doWork()` is called in `A`'s destructor.

This can potentially mess up your data, process, or whatever your class is doing. So, again, I would advise against triggering actual work in a destructor. Better define a separate function in the class for that, and call it at a time that is designated for this particular task. Your code only loses lots of readability and maintainability otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

On one side, the technical possibility:

> 12.7/4: Member functions, including virtual functions, can be called during construction or destruction.

On the other side, the guiding principle that every design should respect:

> 12.4/15 Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists;

I would therefore not advise such a design.

Such a design would be bad pracice.  If a transaction is created, and some requests are added to it, if for any reason the transaction needs to be interrupted (the connected system disapeared, the user wants to interupt, an exception occured, etc...), your design would force the incomplete requests to be carried out.  This doesn't respect the logic all or nothing that one would expect from a transaction.

A better approach would be to design your transaction according to the **[state design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state)**: a transaction would for example have the states:

- created (new, no requests),
- ongoing (requests are being added),
- to-be-executed (no additional requests will be performed),
- and completed (requests were executed) or cancelled.

If destructor is called and state is not completed nor cancelled, the destructor should strive for cancellation.